# How can I add new features to Python Password Generator?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python password generator code and I want to create an option to ask the user if they want to determine which punctuation characters might be in the generator and to store it in a file. Here is the code below:
#importing Libraries

```
from tkinter import *
import random, string
import pyperclip




###initialize window

root =Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("DataFlair - PASSWORD GENERATOR")

#heading
heading = Label(root, text = 'Random Password Generator' , font ='arial 15 bold').pack()
Label(root, text ='DataFlair', font ='arial 15 bold').pack(side = BOTTOM)


###select password length
pass_label = Label(root, text = 'PASSWORD LENGTH', font = 'arial 10 bold').pack()
pass_len = IntVar()
length = Spinbox(root, from_ = 8, to_ = 32 , textvariable = pass_len , width = 15).pack()


#####define function

pass_str = StringVar()

def Generator():
    password = ''
for x in range (0,4):
        password = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)+random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)+random.choice(string.digits)+random.choice(string.punctuation)
for y in range(pass_len.get()- 4):
        password = password+random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation)
        pass_str.set(password)


###button

Button(root, text = "GENERATE PASSWORD" , command = Generator ).pack(pady= 5)

Entry(root , textvariable = pass_str).pack()

########function to copy

def Copy_password():
    pyperclip.copy(pass_str.get())

Button(root, text = 'COPY TO CLIPBOARD', command = Copy_password).pack(pady=5)

# loop to run program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can save passwords to a file, and You can get a word from the user and create a password, I have an old file in my github account but simple.
[passwordgenerator](https://github.com/yasincanolcay/passwordgenerator.git)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).